# Swap out input stream on live ffmpeg process

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, pipe, webrtc

I'm very new to ffmpeg, so I apologize if this is not possible or the answer is obvious. I have an ffmpeg process where I'm recording a stream (audio and video) to .webm file.

This is a webrtc client on my server, and I'd like to switch which stream ffmpeg is taking as input according to who the active speaker is.

It works fine as long as I don't try to mess with the stream (video and audio) with the parameters:

```
 '-loglevel',
  'debug',
  '-protocol_whitelist',
  'pipe,udp,rtp',
  '-fflags',
  '+genpts',
  '-f',
  'sdp',
  '-i',
  'pipe:0',
  '-map',
  '0:v:0',
  '-c:v',
  'copy',
  '-map',
  '0:a:0',
  '-strict',
  '-2',
  '-c:a',
  'copy',
  '-flags',
  '+global_header',
  './recordings/ffmpegrecording.webm'
```

I start the ffmpeg process with node:

```
this._process = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', this._commandArgs);
```

Then I pipe my stream to the ffmpeg process:

```
sdpStream.pipe(this._process.stdin);
```

Is there any way I could replace the input stream without killing the ffmpeg process or otherwise messing it up (wrecking the metadata or other undesired consequences)?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Well, still stumped. My first though was that I might be able to set the stream replacement on another rtp/rtcp ports, unpipe the original stream, setup a new one. `this.sdpStream1.unpipe(this._process.stdin)` then pipe the new stream in `this.sdpStream2.pipe(this._process.stdin)`. However, it is ffmpeg is unable to locate the input when done this way for some reason.

Comment: My second thought was to replace the stream with another on the same ports. ffmpeg is able to pick up the replacement, but with the error: [sdp @ 0x55f5f13f79c0] RTP: PT=65: bad cseq 0001 expected=00dc\n